# How can i sum values of 1 column based on the categories of another column, multiple times, in R?

Tags: r, loops, sum, longitudinal

I guess my question its a little strange, let me try to explain it. I need to solve a simple equation for a longitudinal database (29 consecutive years) about food availability and international commerce: `(importations-exportations)/(production+importations-exportations)*100`[equation for food dependence coeficient, by FAO]. The big problem is that my database has the food products and its values of interest (production, importation and exportation) dissagregated, so i need to find a way to apply that equation to a sum of the values of interest for every year, so i can get the coeficient i need for every year.

My data frame looks like this:

```
element      product   year   value (metric tons)
Production   Wheat     1990   16
Importation  Wheat     1990   2
Exportation  Wheat     1990   1
Production   Apples    1990   80
Importation  Apples    1990   0
Exportation  Apples    1990   72
Production   Wheat     1991   12
Importation  Wheat     1991   20
Exportation  Wheat     1991   0
```

I guess the solution its pretty simple, but im not good enough in R to solve this problem by myself. Every help is very welcome.

Thanks!

[This is a picture of my R session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuBhY.png)

Comment: I'd suggest reshaping the data so the elements are in columns, eg with `library(tidyr); YOUR_TABLE %>% pivot_wider(names_from = element, values_from = 'value (metric tons)')`. Then straightforward to do the calculations almost exactly as you've written them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(data.table)

# dummy table. Use setDT(df) if yours isn't a data table already
df <- data.table(element = (rep(c('p', 'i', 'e'), 3))
                 , product = (rep(c('w', 'a', 'w'), each=3))
                 , year = rep(c(1990, 1991), c(6,3))
                 , value = c(16,2,1,80,0,72,12,20,0)
                 ); df

   element product year value
1:       p       w 1990    16
2:       i       w 1990     2
3:       e       w 1990     1
4:       p       a 1990    80
5:       i       a 1990     0
6:       e       a 1990    72
7:       p       w 1991    12
8:       i       w 1991    20
9:       e       w 1991     0



# long to wide
df_1 <- dcast(df
              , product + year ~ element
              , value.var = 'value'
              ); df_1

# apply calculation
df_1[, food_depend_coef := (i-e) / (p+i-e)*100][]

   product year  e  i  p food_depend_coef
1:       a 1990 72  0 80      -900.000000
2:       w 1990  1  2 16         5.882353
3:       w 1991  0 20 12        62.500000
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution. The only problem its that mi df has something like 2 values for each element, so i need an automated code to compute the equation

Comment: Nevermind, i figure it out a way to apply your solution to my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. Next time try posting your expected results e.g. by creating a dummy table so others can better understand
Welcome to StackOverflow!